# Rails 3 - Help with a Email Validation Regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

the following REGEX if provided an email domain that does not match INVALID_EMAILs seems to run indefinitely and lock up the rails server (my local env).

```
INVALID_EMAILS = %w(gmail.com googlemail.com yahoo.com ymail.com rocketmail.com hotmail.com facebook.com)


  def valid_email_domain(emailAddy)
    reg = Regexp.new /#{User::INVALID_EMAILS.map{|a| Regexp.quote(a)}.join("|")}/
    if emailAddy.scan(reg).size == 0
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end
```

Any regex experts out there that can provide feedback? Thanks

**UPDATED:**

**controller:**

```
  def create

    @user = User.new

    # User EmailVeracity to validate the email address
    email = EmailVeracity::Address.new(params[:user][:email])

    Rails.logger.info 'Email Check Result'
Rails.logger.info valid_email_domain(params[:user][:email])
    Rails.logger.info 'Email Check Result'

    if email.valid?
      Rails.logger.info 'Sign this email up'
    else
      Rails.logger.info 'Bad email, dont touch that'
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end

  end
protected

  def valid_email_domain(emailAddy)
    !(emailAddy =~ /#{User::INVALID_EMAILS.map{|a| Regexp.quote(a)}.join("|")}/)
  end
```

**User Model:**

```
INVALID_EMAILS = %w(gmail.com googlemail.com yahoo.com ymail.com rocketmail.com hotmail.com facebook.com)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're making this way too complicated. This should be enough:

```
def valid_email_domain(email_address)
  !(email_address =~ /#{INVALID_EMAILS.map{|a| Regexp.quote(a)}.join("|")}/)
end
```

Comment: Thanks but something's wrong with the regex, when I have an email that matches an invalid email it works fine and returns false. When I have an email that doesn't match any invalid_emails rails hangs, doesn't respond, gets stuck.

Comment: @AnApprentice: This is not happening with any code that I can see. Please provide more code.

Comment: The regex in this case wouldn't do that. It works perfectly for me, with both valid and invalid emails. You likely have a problem somewhere else in your code; probably the part that calls this method.

Comment: Ryan --- updated with full code above. The Rails local server is just hanging with a bad email domain, meaning not an invalid email domain... Not sure how to debug it when the server just sits there.

Comment: Code updated in the question. still happening. if I enter a gmail or hotmail the logger returns blank (meaning false), with a valid email like bob@echostar.com, rails hangs