# Email validation with specific domains in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, email

What is the best way to exlude certain email addresses (in the validation) in Rails3? I want to exclude domains like "hotmail.com, live.com and gmail.com".

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe u can get some ideas from here: [Rails 3 - Help with a Email Validation Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764863/rails-3-help-with-a-email-validation-regex)
It doesnt give a working solution thou..

Answer (score 1):

```
begin
  Mail::Address.new(email)
  #valid
rescue Mail::Field::ParseError => e
  #invalid
end
```